# Difference between boolean !(aSmile && bSmile) and (!aSmile && !bSmile)

Tags: java, boolean

Total noob question, in this codingBat practice http://codingbat.com/prob/p181646

Why if i put :

```
 return (aSmile && bSmile) || !(aSmile && bSmile);
```

the answer to the given practice is wrong, while if i put

```
 return (aSmile && bSmile) || (!aSmile && !bSmile);
```

the answer is correct, is there any difference between !(aSmile && bSmile) with (!aSmile && !bSmile), or something else that made my first answer wrong?

Comment: De Morgan's Law strikes again.

Answer (score 7):

```
   A   |   B   | !(A && B) |
-------+-------+-----------|
  True |  True |   False   |
  True | False |   True    |
 False |  True |   True    |
 False | False |   True    |
```

---

```
   A   |   B   | !A || !B  |
-------+-------+-----------|
  True |  True |   False   |
  True | False |   True    |
 False |  True |   True    |
 False | False |   True    |
```

---

```
   A   |   B   | !A && !B  |
-------+-------+-----------|
  True |  True |   False   |
  True | False |   False   |
 False |  True |   False   |
 False | False |   True    |
```

`!(A && B)` equals `!A || !B`, so
`!(A && B)` and `!A && !B` are not the same thing

Answer (score 2):

```
!(aSmile && bSmile)
```

Should be:

```
!aSmile || !bSmile
```

Answer (score 2):

The only difference here is between the second operands:

```
!(aSmile && bSmile)
```

and

```
(!aSmile && !bSmile)
```

Some useful laws to know are [de Morgan's Laws](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) which say that the first is equivalent to:

```
(!aSmile || !bSmile)
```

While the second is equivalent to:

```
!(aSmile || bSmile)
```

Given these laws, hopefully you can see why the two expressions are different!

Answer (score 1):

```
!(True && False) == !(False) == True
(!True && !False) == (False && True) == False
```

Here we can clearly see why it's a difference between the two statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
(aSmile && bSmile) || !(aSmile && bSmile)
```

This will always be true. If you analyse this, you will see why. `(aSmile && bSmile)` can be either true or false. If it were true, then the whole expression will be true. If it were false, then `!(aSmile && bSmile)` would be true, again making the whole expression true.

In words, the left means "they are both smiling", the right means "they are **not both** smiling (one of them is, or none of them is)"

```
(aSmile && bSmile) || (!aSmile && !bSmile)
```

With this, when `(aSmile && bSmile)` is false, `(!aSmile && !bSmile)` might be false as well. The left means "they are both smiling", the right means "they are **both not** smiling (none of them is)". The expression will be false when only one of them is smiling.

Your boolean expression can be simplified to:

```
aSmile == bSmile
```